# pass value from one page to another in php with fb login

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook php sdk and trying to send token-id from one page to another. I am currently using this code - http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/ . I am using     `$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.krizna.com/fbconfig.php' );`

Facebook login works but I am unable to send token_id from one page to another. I have tried 
    `$_SESSION['token'] = "12345";`

and

```
if($_SESSION['token']){
}
```

in another php but it still does not work. I have also tried 
    `$token=$_GET['token'];`
 by sending value to
`http://www.krizna.com/fbconfig.php?token=12345`
but it's still not working. How can I get it to work and pass value for my token ?

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()` before accessing the `$_SESSION` variable?

Comment: yes all 3 phps have session_start() on top.

Comment: Did you try isset($_SESSION["token"])?

Comment: I tried that and it's still not working. I tried accessing the value from session in fbconfig.php file but I am getting null value. I am unable to make sense of FacebookRedirectLoginHelper . How can I pass value to fbconfig.php ?